# DbManager helper class for Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I'm trying to do a generic Db cotext helper\manager so I can use it as a dll in many projects with different data bases.

I tried to use it with one of my projects but I got confused with the attach and detach in the Add and Edit methods. I'm getting errors as "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker."

Could someone help me to get this manager perfect?

```
public class DbEntityManager<T> : IDisposable where T : class, IEntity
    {
        public DbContext DbEntities { get; set; }

        public virtual int AddNewObject(T objToAdd)
        {
            DbEntities.Set<T>().Add(objToAdd);
            return DbEntities.SaveChanges();
        }

        public virtual int EditObject(T objToEdit)
        {
            if (DbEntities.Entry(objToEdit).State == EntityState.Detached)
            {
                DbEntities.Set<T>().Attach(objToEdit);
                DbEntities.Entry(objToEdit).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
            else
            {
                DbEntities.Entry(objToEdit).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }

            return DbEntities.SaveChanges();
        }

        public virtual int DeleteObject(T objToDelete)
        {
            DbEntities.Set<T>().Remove(objToDelete);
            return DbEntities.SaveChanges();
        }

        public virtual List<T> GetAllList()
        {
            return DbEntities.Set<T>().ToList();
        }

        public virtual T GetObjectById(int id)
        {
            return DbEntities.Set<T>().AsEnumerable().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        }

        public DbEntityManager(DbContext db)
        {
            DbEntities = db;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:** Trying to explain better what I'm reffering.

The IEntity is an interface just to be able to use the GetObjectById function:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; }
}
```

Here is an example of a class:

```
public partial class Address : IEntity
    {
        public Address()
        {
            this.Customers = new HashSet<Customer>();
        }

        public int AddressID { get; set; }
        public string Address_Country { get; set; }
        public string Address_City { get; set; }
        public string Address_Street { get; set; }
        public string Address_ZipCode { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

        public int Id
        {
            get { return AddressID; }
        }
    }
```

So I can use the code like this: Making a manager just for the class

```
public class AddressManager : DbEntityManager<Address>
    {
        public AddressManager()
            : base (new MySystemEntities())
        {
        }
    }
```

And then use it the code (in winform/mvc or whatever):

```
AddressManager manager = new AddressManager ();
Address address = new Address();
address = manager.GetObjectById(id);
```

Or:

```
Address address = new Address();
address.Address_Country = "USA";
manager.AddNewObject(address);
```

Before I did this I searched the internet to see if a class like this already exist, but I didn't find any. So if anyone knows a class already made with these functions I'd be glad to use it.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What are you expecting to get out of the abstraction?

Comment: This question should be a better fit on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Like I said, I want to use it as a dll for many projects that have different db's. I don't want in every project to create the "Add, SaveChanges" and all this all over.

Comment: I've actually built something like this myself. Essentially (to answer @DeanWard's question) it's a completely generic data access class - both in the C# sense of `Foo<T>(T obj)`, and in that it's unrelated to any data storage method (SQL, XML, etc). What you're doing in one class, I've split into two - the generic data manager, and a variety of adapters that connect it to different data sources. One adapter is for SQL using Entity Framework, and so would fill exactly the niche you're describing. I'm actually planning to put it on NuGet sometime in the next few days, if you're interested.

Comment: You say this is a wrapper around `DbContext`, but it appears to really be a wrapper around a `DbSet<TEntity>`. Are you clear in the purpose (writing *why* you are doing this, your motivation, here should help us and yourself better understand why). Without definitions of `IEntity` and `DbEntities` this code is not at all clear.

Comment: Thank's @anaximander I would be glad to see it.

Comment: @DeanWard to further elaborate on why this is useful, it allows for a consistent method for accessing persistent data. This is nice, because your logic code then looks the same regardless of data source (SQL, XML, REST endpoint, whatever). The *real* benefit, however, is that your logic code now uses this persistence-agnostic data source, so you can swap your MS-SQL database adapter for a SQLite adapter and your logic code doesn't even notice (especially when combined with IoC). This lets you move logic to another platform - server, desktop, smartphone, whatever - with zero code changes.

Comment: @anaximander untill you'll upload it to NuGet, could you help me with my class? I really need it. Thanks again.

Comment: Right, until you need the more advanced features that your data access framework provides... In my experience this level of abstraction is really unnecessary in most applications. If you need to access data from library code then expose it via an interface that the consuming application needs to implement... Only scenario I can imagine this being useful would be in an application where the data layer is interchangeable. Maybe that's your scenario :)

Comment: @DeanWard There's a few reasons. I like consistency, so using the same syntax everywhere is nice. Also, I wrote this as a student, so there were frequent changes to the underlying data store when I discovered something better, or learned how to do things that I couldn't before, or because I was broke and moved hosting platforms whenever I found something cheaper. I also changed my mind about how certain features would be implemented, so data would move from client to server or vice versa. And of course, having most of your DAL as pre-built package to drop in lets you prototype things faster.

Answer (score 1):

I have generally used the Repository along with the [UnitOfWork](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx) pattern.

Try implementing such a base repository and then created derived entity types using the same.

That will help keep your code DRY.

```
public interface IBaseRepository<TEntity> : IDisposable
     where TEntity : class
    {
        void Delete(object id);
        void Delete(TEntity entity);
        TEntity Find(params object[] keyValues);
        void Insert(TEntity entity);
        void InsertRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);
        IQueryable<TEntity> SelectQuery(string query, params object[] parameters);
        void Update(TEntity entity);
        void RefreshEntityContext(TEntity entity);
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Edit: Ok, here is an extract of the implementation (similar to how I have implemented it):

```
namespace ContosoUniversity.DAL
{
    public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        internal SchoolContext context;
        internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

        public GenericRepository(SchoolContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = "")
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }

            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
                (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                return orderBy(query).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                return query.ToList();
            }
        }

        public virtual TEntity GetByID(object id)
        {
            return dbSet.Find(id);
        }

        public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
        {
            dbSet.Add(entity);
        }

        public virtual void Delete(object id)
        {
            TEntity entityToDelete = dbSet.Find(id);
            Delete(entityToDelete);
        }

        public virtual void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete)
        {
            if (context.Entry(entityToDelete).State == EntityState.Detached)
            {
                dbSet.Attach(entityToDelete);
            }
            dbSet.Remove(entityToDelete);
        }

        public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
        {
            dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
            context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
}
```

You can now inherit your repositories from the GenericRepository and have all the basic CRUD operations available.

from,
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Interface won't help me here.

Comment: @user2254436 - you need to implement the interface as I have done the same in my project that facilitates a reusable repository base class as described in the 'UnitOfWork' implementation shared above. 
Did you go through the pattern?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to do something like the following:

```
public virtual int EditObject(T objToEdit)
    {
        var curval = DB.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == objToEdit.Id);
        //You may want to make all your entities inherit from the same 
        //baseclass to get Id
        if (curval == null)
        {
            DB.Set<T>.Add(objToEdit);
        }
        else
        {
            DB.Entry(curval).CurrentValues.SetValues(objToEdit);
            DB.Entry(curval).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        }
        return DB.SaveChanges();
    }
```

it's quite easy to modify this code to work with Models too.

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel. Try [NRepository](https://nrepository.codeplex.com/), it's a generic repository (yes, another one) with an entity framework extension and uses strategies for reuse rather then service methods.Plus its fully testable without mocks.

```
IQueryRepository queryRepository = new EntityFrameworkQueryRepository(new YourDbContext()) ;
var address = queryRepository.GetEntity<Address>(
    p => p.AddressID == 2,
    new AsNoTrackingQueryStrategy(),
    new EagerLoadingQueryStrategy<Address>(
        p => p.Customers));
```

Or to add entities as well as just use :

```
IRepository repository = new EntityFrameworkRepository(new YourDbContext()) ;
var address = new Address{ Address_City = "Leeds" };
repository.Add(address);
repository.Save()
```

N.B. Don't forget to inject in your repositories :)

Answer (score 0):

entity framework already use repository and unit of work design pattern, no need for an helpers to work with that framework